# How to write a macro wrapper for a method in Objective-C++

Tags: objective-c++

I have a lot of this in my work codebase:

```
  __typeof(self) __weak weakSelf = self;
  dispatch_async(_queue, ^{
    auto strongSelf = weakSelf;
    if (!strongSelf) {
      return;
    }
    [strongSelf doSomething:aParam paramB:paramB];
  });
```

I'd like to replace all the boilerplate with a macro. Something like:

```
#define RUN_SAFELY_ON_QUEUE(q_, METHOD)  \
  __typeof(self) __weak weakSelf = self; \
  dispatch_async(q_, ^{                  \
  auto strongSelf = weakSelf;            \
  if (!strongSelf) {                     \
    return;                              \
  }                                      \
  METHOD()                               \
});                                      \
```

And then run things like:

```
RUN_SAFELY_ON_QUEUE(_queue, [self doSomething:aParam paramB:paramB]);
```

Currently, I'm getting the error: `"Called object type 'void' is not a function or function pointer"`.

Is what I'm looking for possible?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Replace `METHOD()` with `METHOD;`?

Comment: @sbooth Removing the () after calling METHOD is one of the steps. The other is to add () around METHOD and q_. I've added an answer below if you're curious

Answer (score 0):

This works, and make sure to add () around the param:

```
    #define RUN_SAFELY(q_, METHOD)         \
    __weak __typeof(self) weakSelf = self; \
    dispatch_async((q_), ^{                  \
        auto strongSelf = weakSelf;        \
        if (!strongSelf) {                 \
            return;                        \
        }                                  \
        (METHOD);                            \
    });                                    \
```

And use it like so:

```
RUN_SAFELY(dispatch_get_main_queue(), [self doSomething:aParam paramB:paramB]);
```